# Loading JSON data with CSV Data Set Config

Tags: json, jmeter, config

I'm new to Jmeter so I hope this question is not too off the wall.  I am trying to test an HTTP endpoint that accepts a large JSON payload and processes it.  I have collected a few hundred JSON blobs in a file and want to use those as my input for testing.  The only way that I have come across for loading the data is using the CSV config.  I have a single line of the file for each request.  I have attempted to use \n as a delimiter and have also tried adding a tab character \t to the end of each line.  My requests all show in put of`<EOF>`.

Is there a way to read a file of JSON objects, line at a time, and pass them to my endpoint as the body in a POST?

Comment: this is a good question, however you need to provide an example of the input that is not working, as there may be many reasons

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more information, to wit: example JSON file (first 2 lines), your CSV Data Set Configuration, *jmeter.log* file, etc. so we could help.

For the time being I can state that:

1. Given CSV file looking like:

   ```
   {"foo":"bar"}
   {"baz":"qux"}
   ```
2. And pretty much default [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) setup

   [image: JMeter CSV Data Set Config]
3. JMeter normally reads the CSV data

   [image: JMeter CSV Data Set Config]

---

Be aware that there are alternatives to the CSV Data Set Config, for example:

- [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead). The equivalent syntax would be `${__CSVRead(test.csv,0)}`
- [__StringFromFile() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile). The equivalent syntax would be `${__StringFromFile(test.csv,,,)}`

See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) to get familiarized with the JMeter Functions concept.